# Spark Structured streaming - dropDuplicates with watermark alternate solution

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to deduplicate on streaming data using the dropDuplicate function with watermark. The problem I am facing currently is that I have to two timestamps for a given record

1. One is the eventtimestamp - timestamp of the record creation from the source.
2. Another is an transfer timestamp - timestamp from an intermediate process that is responsible to stream the data.

The duplicates are introduced during the intermediate stage so for a given a record duplicate, the eventtimestamp is same but transfer timestamp is different.

For the watermark, I like to use the transfertimestamp because I know the duplicates cant occur more than 3 minutes apart in transfer. But I cant use it within dropDuplicate because it wont capture the duplicates as the duplicates have different transfer timestamp.

Here is an example,

```
Event 1:{ "EventString":"example1", "Eventtimestamp": "2018-11-29T10:00:00.00", "TransferTimestamp": "2018-11-29T10:05:00.00" }
Event 2 (duplicate): {"EventString":"example1", "Eventtimestamp": "2018-11-29T10:00:00.00", "TransferTimestamp": "2018-11-29T10:08:00.00"}
```

In this case, the duplicate was created during transfer after 3 mins from the original event

My code is like below,

```
streamDataset.
.withWatermark("transferTimestamp", "4 minutes")
.dropDuplicates("eventstring","transferTimestamp");
```

The above code won't drop the duplicates as transferTimestamp is unique for the event and its duplicate. But currently, this is the only way as Spark forces me to include the watermark column in the dropDuplicates function when watermark is set.

I would really like to see an dropDuplicate implementation like below which would be a valid case for any at-least once semantics streams where I dont have to use the watermark field in dropDuplicates and still the watermark based state eviction is honored. But that is not the case currently

```
streamDataset.
.withWatermark("transferTimestamp", "4 minutes")
.dropDuplicates("eventstring");
```

I cant use the eventtimestamp as it is not ordered and time range varies drastically (delayed events and junk events).

If anyone has an alternate solution or ideas for deduping in such scenario, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you cant use the dropDuplicates API directly . You have to use a arbitrary stateful operation for the same using some spark API like flatmapgroupwithstate

Answer (score 0):

for the above case, should not below work?

```
streamDataset.
.withWatermark("Eventtimestamp", "4 or 5 minutes")
.dropDuplicates("eventstring","Eventtimestamp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.5.0, the functionality that you are referring to is supported by the `dropDuplicatesWithinWatermark` operator. From the [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication):

> [It] can be used to deal with use case where event time column cannot be a part of unique identifier, mostly due to the case where event times are somehow different for the same records. (E.g. non-idempotent writer where issuing event time happens at write)

Thus, your exact code snippet at the end can be made to work:

```
streamDataset
    .withWatermark("transferTimestamp", "4 minutes")
    .dropDuplicatesWithinWatermark("eventstring");
```

---

For readers who might still be confused about this use-case, consider the following records of (timestamp, value):

- (5, "foo")
- (6, "foo")

You want to deduplicate on value, but you also need to remove state based on the timestamp. Before Spark 3.5.0, you might call `dropDuplicates(["timestamp", "value"])`. However, these records would then be considered unique, since `(5, "foo") != (6, "foo")`. However, in Spark 3.5.0+ you could write:

```
df
 .withWatermark("timestamp", "4 minutes")
 .dropDuplicatesWithinWatermark("value")
```

Here, Spark will remove state based on `timestamp`, but only do duplication comparison on the `value` column. Thus, it would compare `"foo"` to `"foo"`, and find the duplicate. Thus, only (5, "foo") would be emitted downstream.